# I want to create a ember table component whose value is updated dynamically [Ember.js]

Tags: ember.js, ember-table, orbit.js

when i bind a tracked variable to the ember table, this is the error that i get

> Error: Assertion Failed: You attempted to update rows on <(unknown):ember472>, but it had already been used previously in the same computation. Attempting to update a value after using it in a computation can cause logical errors, infinite revalidation bugs, and performance issues, and is not supported.
>
> rows was first used:

So how do i go about creating a table which changes the value according to the value in the tracked variable

this is the controller side

```
@tracked rows = this.model.row
```

this is the component side

```
<EmberTable as |t|>
  <t.head @columns={{@columns}} @widthConstraint="eq-container" />
  <t.body @rows={{@rows}} as |b|>
    <b.row as |r|>
       <r.cell as |value|>
         {{value}}
       </r.cell>
    </b.row>
  </t.body>
</EmberTable>
```

i passed the row variable to the component and the table rendered just fine.

but at times the values inside the model.data changes and then this error occurs

Comment: Please provide some examples of your code.

Comment: edited the question with some examples @james

Comment: It doesn't look like ember-table works nicely with the newest version of ember yet,